# Android java for loop breaks suddenly

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have the following code running:

```
public static Level getNextLevel(Context context, int id)
{
    boolean found = false;
    ArrayList<Level> levels = getLevels(context);
    for(Level lvl : levels)
    {
        if (found)
        {
            return lvl;
        }
        if (lvl.id==id)
        {
            found=true;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I trace it, the second if works and variable found becomes true, then another iteration goes and when it gets to line "if (found)", I check and variable found is true, but it then breaks of the for block instead of going into the if block!

The ArrayList levels has 5 items and it happens just after the first item is checked.

Any suggestions why this might happen?

Comment: I think you need swap two if with each, that means first you need check id then if found equals to true return `l`

Comment: No, the order of the if blocks are correct. I want to find the next item, and it does on paper!
The problem is that when found is true, it does not enter the if and it just skips to return null

Comment: so this must be worked, what is the problem? did you debug your code?

Comment: Yes, it must work. I debugged it and as I explained, it does not enter the first if block ever!
When found becomes true by the second if and it re-enters the for loop for next iteration and gets to first if (now found is true), it does not enter the if and just breaks out of the for loop and returns null

Comment: in debug mode it's normal, skip from loop and wait on `return null;`, when founds equals to true, check `l` value, and check return value on where ever called this method

Comment: Why in debug mode it's normal?
Also, the returned value is null in the calling method.

Comment: what is `l`? maybe `l` is null too

Comment: l (or lvl now) is read from the ArrayList and is not null

Comment: If your lvl.id==id becomes true for the last item of your arraylist, then your logic returns null. Maybe that's your issue. Also it may be a compile issue, try to recompile your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your method getNextLevel() tries to yield the successor of the entry in `ArrayList<Level> levels` which is equal to `id`. But if `id` matches the last entry then the for-loop ends and you get `null`.

Comment: @Rose: Thanks. Then, you are welcome to click the "up"-arrow ;-) Anyway, without further information and feedback of the questioner a perfectly accurate answer is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You say that `found` becomes true at the first iteration, then logically the next iteration will  enter the first `if` and call `return l`, which means your loop will stop.

So the question is: should the first iteration have set `found` to true?

Comment: No, My problem is logically found becomes true at the appropriate time, but when the it becomes true and gets to line "if (found)", it does not enter the if block even though found is true. instead, it goes out of the for block (whilst the iterations are not complete) and returns null instead of l.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
After examining your question further it seems that you will want to remove `return 1;` entirely. As your for loop actually enters the `if (found)` block but return forces it to exist the loop and the whole method.

Answer (score 0):

FYI the returned "l" is not the found "l"
because it is returned in the next loop, which is the next item in the arraylist

anyways, i suggest you method to be like this

```
public static Level getNextLevel(Context context, int id){
    //boolean found = false; no need
    ArrayList<Level> levels = getLevels(context);
    for(Level lvl : levels)
    {
        if (lvl.id==id)
        {
             return lvl ;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

i replaced l with lvl to make it clear, it looks 1 and l looks similar on some fonts.

Comment: As the title of the method suggests, I want to find the next Item.
The algorithm is correct. My problem is with java's strange behavior regarding my code

Comment: ok now i got what you mean, but i can't find anything wrong in your code, unless the found id is the last item in the array, so next loop will not occur, otherwise, this is really strange, can you provide the Level bean? and some sample data, i mean a simulation for getLevels(), i would like to run this code on my machine\

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking good

```
    boolean found = false;
    ArrayList<Level> levels = getLevels(context);
    for(Level lvl : levels)
    {
        if (found)
        {
            return lvl;
        }
        if (lvl.id==id)
        {
            found=true;
        }
    }
    return null;
```

You may try following loop for what you are trying to achieve

```
for(int i=0; i<levels.size()-1; i++){
   if(levels.get(i).id ==id )
   {
     return levels.get(i+1);
   }


}
```